# trying to pass a prop in React, but cant find the way

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass this: `data-html2canvas-ignore="true"` into an element which is being rendered as `<g class="recharts-layer recharts-brush chart-brush chart-brush-hidden">` which comes from

`className={'chart-brush ${!mouseOverChart && 'chart-brush-hidden'}'}`

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the thing I just told you that I need to pass (`data-html2canvas-ignore="true"`).

Comment: Did you try passing a boolean prop and saying data-html2canvas-ignore=props.ignore in the child component?

Comment: I'm using typescript. I have to somehow pass that prop from an interface. But I get syntax errors when I put `-` chars.

Comment: Can you show that interface and what you're trying to pass to? Generally interfaces don't implement anything so I don't see how it would pass a value.

Comment: I'm tryin to do this now: `hide: {[data-html2canvas-ignore]?: boolean};` Showing you the interface will not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: just pass the htmlParam to your component as string

```
<g
  className={'chart-brush ${!mouseOverChart && 'chart-brush-hidden'}'}
  data-html2canvas-ignore="true">
</g>
```

Update: did you tried it at your Interface declaration?

```
export interface BrushProps {
  className?: string;
  fill?: string;
  stroke?: string;
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
  ['data-html2canvas-ignore']?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: What is happening?

Comment: I have to pass it through the interface, otherwise it's not going to work, I've tried...

Comment: It seem's that you want to get the prop from ts, is it correct?

Comment: I want to define the prop on the interface and use it.

Comment: Strange I'm using the same syntax, and it's working

Comment: How is it going to work if you don't even have the contents of `!mouseOverChart`?

Comment: slashs will not work on object key assignment, try this: `hide: {['data-html2canvas-ignore']?: boolean};`

Comment: I mean I'm using this htmlParam on react project, and the component is being ignored.

Comment: No idea, but this is now happening: `Property 'hide' is missing in type '{ onChange: (event: any) => void;`.

Comment: Oh, had to add the prop to all loaded components

Comment: can you show a piece of your code? and where you trying to declare the prop?

Comment: And what's the result of that code, where are you using the interface? I mean can you show a piece of code of component that is using that interface?

Comment: umm, those are props and I'm using them on a component.

Comment: Woops, noticed that the interface was inside a node file, I'm not supposed to edit that one, any other idea on how should I make it?

Comment: try to explain the context at all, maybe we can have some other idea to active the same result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618463/how-to-add-prop-if-component-only-has-its-props-defined-in-an-index-d-ts-file